How to apply media query to object CSS in Nextjs
I wrote the CSS inside an object and exported it so the component can use it.
style.ts
import { CSSType } from '@/types/Common';

const styles: CSSType = {
  concurrentCard: {
    width: 300,
    border: '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125)',
    padding: '1rem',
  },
};

export default styles;

I want to make the width 200 when the screen is 425px or below.
I've tried to ask in chatgpt but it's not working.
chatgpt
styles['@media (max-width: 425px)'] = {
  concurrentCard: {
    width: '200px'
  },
};

I will appreciate any help, thanks in advance.
